# How to skip XML file reading to end of current parent element using QXMLStreamReader?

Tags: xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

Assume that I have an XML file's data as follows:

```
<Parent-1>
      <Child-1>Info-1</Child-1>
      <Child-2>Info-2</Child-2>
      <Child-3>Info-3</Child-3>
</Parent-1>
<Parent-2>
      <Child-1>Info-1</Child-1>
      <Child-2>Info-2</Child-2>
      <Child-3>Info-3</Child-3>
</Parent-2>
<Parent-3>
      <Child-1>Info-1</Child-1>
      <Child-2>Info-2</Child-2>
      <Child-3>Info-3</Child-3>
</Parent-3>
```

When I read the file from the beginning, first I read the start element **Parent-1**, and then its first child **Child-1** and its text **Info-1**.

If the **Parent-1/Child-1**'s **Info-1** is equal to some specific value eg: *SKIP*, then I want to skip the entire **Parent-1** element, and read next parent element **Parent-2**.

As far as I know, **QXMLStreamReader** provides only *skipCurrentElement()* and *readNextStartElement()*, which will read until the next start element, in my case **Parent-1**'s **Child-2**.

Is there any way to skip the entire parent element? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If calling `skipCurrentElement()` twice does not work, you should easily be able to skip with a simple loop

```
while (!isEndElement() || name() != "Parent-1") {
    readNext();
}
```

Comment: This isn't a sufficient answer because it doesn't take tree depth into account. Here's a simple counterexample: `<Parent-1><Child-1>Info-1</Child-1><Parent-1></Parent-1></Parent-1>`

Comment: The example in the question doesn't have that kind of structure, nor is there any indication in the text for that either,

Comment: Thank you @KevinKrammer. Fortunately my XML file has no such nested tag structure. A small question again: Is there any anyway to seek to end of file using QXMLStreamReader without reading all lines using _readNext()_ in a loop?

Comment: @Yarram I don't think there is but what would be the purpose of reading until the end? If at some point you know that you don't need any of the rest of the data, just stop reading